# iphone development: how to auto facebook login if the facebook app already logged in

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

In my app users can login by using facebook. I also have Facebook official app in my mobile phone and it is logged in. When I try to login from my app it asks for email and password. Is it possible to auto login if facebook app already logged in? How can I do that? because I know almost all apps use this feature

Comment: I'm not sure that that's possible or not; it might be but if it is, what if the user doesn't want you to do that? Surely you have to ask the user first whether to use their facebook login?

Comment: @daveL yes of course, there will be a facebook connect button, if the user presses it and already have a logged in session in Facebook app, the app should be automatically logged in with facebook.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered Facebook SDK for iOS?  Here is the link: https://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Comment: I already have Facebook SDK. Could not understand your point?

Comment: If you authenticate using FBSession, you should see the Permissions dialog in facebook app.It would not ask for email and password if you  are logged in.

Comment: Actually yes I use FBSession and when I login it say You are already authorized "appname" but still when I log out inside the app but not the from the facebook app, if the facebook login pressed it asks for the user information again

Comment: @death7eater , i have same problem did you fix this problem? if yes,please provide a way to fix it. Thanks in Advance